# Get value from Javascript to HTML in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I want to ask that how can I call a value from javascript to html blade in laravel.

**Here is my JavaScript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueFunction(){
        var output = document.getElementById('teacherId').value;
        console.log(output);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    }
</script>
```

**Here is my Laravel Html:**

```
<select id="teacherId" onchange="valueFunction()">
                        <option>Select Teacher</option>
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
{{$users[]->name}}
<output id="output"></output>
```

Controller Code:

```
$users = User::all();
    $students = Students::all();
    return view('admin.assignStudent', compact('users','students'));
```

As I am getting the value in output tag, but I want to call the value of javascrpt in `{{$users[output]->name}}` here.

Thank you.

Comment: change <output id="output"></output> . to <div id="output"></div>

Comment: Your current solution is the best ! Print value with mixing javascript and php variable is a bad idea ..

Comment: I want to print detail about the selected user thats why i need id to get the data from database

Comment: can you show your controller code? thanks

Comment: added controller code

Answer (score 1):

In laravel or any other PHP framework you have to call java script function as follows:

`{{'<script>valueFunction()</script>'}}`

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel Html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var users = @json($users);
    function valueFunction(){
        var userId = document.getElementById('teacherId').value;
        var user = array.filter(function(arr){return arr.id == userId})[0];
        console.log(user);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = user.name;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to call it dynamically, as:

`var outputs = document.getElementById('teacherId').value;
   document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '{{$user[outputs]->name}}';`

but i cant call output in `'{{$user[outputs]->name}}'`, it is returning error **Use of undefined constant outputs **

Comment: My English is not good. Can you describe input and output, pattern?

Comment: No problem, the output is the value from dropdown menu in html, dropdown menu is getting options from loop. so m getting selected value in javascript and want to send value to html to print the value in html.

Comment: I really want to help you, but I really don't understand what you want. Avoid losing your time, others may help better

Comment: will edit my code in question, it may help you to understand it better

Comment: I understand. 2 way: 1> using API with AJAX. 2> Create array javascript from $users. I think so 2 way then easier

Comment: can you guide me how to create that array as, am getting error while creating array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, as JavaScript is only executed in the client side without interaction with the blade file.

A suggestion is to set up an API in Laravel, use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in JavaScript and `POST` (or other HTTP verbs) to the route. Process and return the data in Laravel. Finally display it in the DOM using JavaScript.

Or if you want the blade template to use the value directly, you may want to use a HTML `form` to post to Laravel, process the data, then return the view along with the data. Doing so requires the user to navigate to another page (or to the same page again).

Answer (score 0):

try this and see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function valueFunction(){
        var output = document.getElementById('teacherId').value;
        console.log(output);


        var data = {!! $sites[output]->name() !!};
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = data ;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, Tested this getting error : `Use of undefined constant output - assumed 'output'`